# Installing lighttpd in CentOS 6.0

Tags: linux, webserver, centos, lighttpd

I never used CentOS, I only used Ubuntu, and I'm really new in web server matters. I couldn't find any easy way to install Lighttpd in CentOS 6.0. Could anyone please instruct me how to install Lighttpd in CentOS 6.0? Waiting for help.

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Lighttpd+%22CentOS+6%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide is very easy and just works:
http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-lighttpd-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-centos-6.0

Comment: Answers should be self-contained in such a way the asker doesn't have to look at the links, similar to the way Lone Coder explained it.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following to add the proper repo and install it.

```
wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.i686.rpm
rpm -Uhv rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.i686.rpm
yum install lighttpd
```

Or for 64bit

```
wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uhv rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
yum install lighttpd
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo yum list available 'lighttpd*'

this should tell you which lighttpd package are available for your arch and you can then do

yum install package.

Comment: Add epel and rpmforge to your repo lists first